# How to automatically INSERT or UPDATE with SQLite.Net?

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite-net

I'm using the SQLite.Net Async API. Is there a way to have it automatically `INSERT` or `UPDATE` depending on the entity's primary key which is defined as `[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]`?

I can see from the intellisense that there are `InsertAsync()` and `UpdateAsync()` but no information about how they work in case the primary key property is already set in the entity.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, people. The supposed original is about constructing a SQL statement to get the effect of an upsert. This question is about how the API works, and if there is a method call in it which performs an insert or replace.

Comment: @KeithRobertson Thanks. Some folks are not aware that SQLite is not equal to SQLite.Net.